# C# build in VS - separate API references?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, build

Here's the scenario in VS 2008: I have App1 and App2 and both of them contain references to custom Library1. Library1 has references to API1 which is only used by App1 and API2 which is only used by App2. However, when I build App1 it contains all of the libraries/files required by **both** API1 and API2 (and vice-versa). Is there a way to ensure that a build of App1 will only contain the references needed by Library1 for that build?

Comment: If App1 doesn't use any classes in Library1 that are related to API2, then App1 shouldn't need a reference to API2. You can't avoid Library1 having a reference to both API1 and API2 though, if you don't want to have two different versions of Library1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, since the library is built without any knowledge about who is going to use which references inside it. So all references are linked when building the library, no matter how many applications (this could be zero) you've got referencing the library.

You can access API1 from Library1 and create a new library Library2 to access API2 if it's that important that the implementation is separated.

Comment: Thank you, I figured that it wasn't possible. In my OP I forgot to mention that I wanted to keep a single library so the option you mentioned wouldn't work for me.